# Is poaching a foie gras torchon really necessary?

Tags: poaching, liver

Is poaching the torchon really necessary?

Can't I skip the poaching and just wrap, chill, and serve?

Answer (score 2):

Poaching a foie gras torchon is not necessary. Essentially, the liver is a cured charcuterie before the poaching step would occur. From this  [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/12/the-food-lab-how-to-make-a-foie-gras-torchon.html)  method of preparation:

> To Cook or Not To Cook?
>
> At this stage, the most classical of recipes will have you poach your torchon in a bath of sub-simmering hot water for about 20 minutes, long enough to bring the whole thing into the range of 130 to 140°F, effectively cooking it. More modern recipes, such as Thomas Keller's go for a much, much shorter cooking time—about 90 seconds. Tasted side by side, I've always preferred the shorter cooking time. The foie is denser, has a more buttery texture, and doesn't leak as much fat when you slice it or eat it.
>
> I always wondered why this was until I came to what was a pretty obvious realization: Thomas Keller's 90-second poached torchon is essentially uncooked. I stuck a thermometer into a torchon during its simmer and measured the internal temperature. It started at around 40°F, and finished exactly where it started. Aside from the outer few millimeters, absolutely no cooking occurs in a 90-second poached foie. No wonder the texture is so significantly different—we're essentially eating raw cured liver here!
>
> There is, however, a good reason to poach the foie, even if it's only for a brief period: The exterior layers soften enough that you can wrap the cheesecloth even tighter, giving you a better looking finished product. That Thomas Keller poach is really all about appearances!

For those not familiar, this article from  [D'Artagnan](http://www.dartagnan.com/foie-gras-terrine-vs-torchon.html)  explains the differences in foie gras terrine and foie gras torchon. (No endorsement intended, just good info.)